# How do you upgrade an AWS instance from Windows Server 2008 32-bit to 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance (medium) running Windows Server 2008 32-bit version. I would like to upgrade it to Windows Server 2008 R2. Is it possible to do that without reinstalling all the applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it isn't.

You can't upgrade from a Windows 32-bit OS to a Windows 64-bit OS.